# X11 Forwarding under Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, hosting, x11, forwarding

Which X11 forwarding under Windows solution do you recommmend ?
I'd like to get the X11 display (lxde) from my dedicated hosting Ubuntu Server 
on my Windows home computer so I can remote administrate (I'm a linux newbie).

Comment: You should probably ask this question at: http://superuser.com/ - it's exactly like StackOverflow, only for Unix/Linux issues. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux there are 2 main protocols that you can use to forward a whole desktop (more options if you just want a single app):

- NX: as available from FreeNX, neatx, x2go, and nomachine
- VNC: TigerVNC, TightVNC, RealVNC, etc - generally available with the OS
  (Windows has RDP built-in, but I wouldn't recommend a newbie to try to install xrdp on Linux, not even non-newbies!)

You can find a [comparison here](http://winswitch.org/documentation/protocols/choose.html) under "Full Desktop Mode". Sorry, I am only allowed to post one link, so I posted a meta-link.

There are other proprietary options too, not mentioned here.

Comment: I finally avoid x11 forwarding solutions to administrate a server

Answer (score 1):

Use FreeNX ( http://freenx.berlios.de/ ). Ten minutes for tuning and you can run your X11-session through ssh.

If you want forward single X11-application, use mingw and putty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the whole desktop. Use PuTTY's X forwarding and run the appropriate command via SSH.